# Why am I not getting an onload handler?

Tags: javascript

I have several images I am trying to load. Each one has is connected to a single handler intended to check if all the images are displaying, and if so, display them on a canvas.

The handler, presently with a console.log() at the top, is:

```
POCKETWATCH.check_draw_clock = function()
    {
    console.log("check_draw_clock");
    POCKETWATCH.images_loaded_count += 1;
    if (POCKETWATCH.images_loaded_count ==
      POCKETWATCH.total_images_available * 2)
        {
        POCKETWATCH.draw_clock();
        }
    }
```

I start to load the images:

```
console.log('Starting images.');
POCKETWATCH.clock_face = new Image();
POCKETWATCH.clock_face.onload = POCKETWATCH.check_draw_clock;
POCKETWATCH.clock_face.src = 'img/transparent-clock.png';
POCKETWATCH.hour_hand = new Image();
POCKETWATCH.hour_hand.onload = POCKETWATCH.check_draw_clock;
POCKETWATCH.hour_hand.src = 'img/hour-hand.png';
POCKETWATCH.minute_hand = new Image();
POCKETWATCH.minute_hand.onload = POCKETWATCH.check_draw_clock;
POCKETWATCH.minute_hand.src = 'img/minute-hand.png';
POCKETWATCH.second_hand = new Image();
POCKETWATCH.second_hand.onload = POCKETWATCH.check_draw_clock;
POCKETWATCH.second_hand.src = 'img/second-hand.png';
POCKETWATCH.dial_hand = new Image();
POCKETWATCH.dial_hand.onload = POCKETWATCH.check_draw_clock;
POCKETWATCH.dial_hand.src = 'img/dial-hand.png';
console.log('Images all started.');
```

The console after this has no errors, just "Starting images." and "Images all started.", with no "check_draw_clock" and no errors. The images are copied from another project of mine and as far as I can tell there are appropriate filesystem permissions etc. and the images are all there.

How am I getting statements that the images are being loaded with no reference to the callback function and no reported errors?

--UPDATE--

In response to the first answer, I commented out my existing code and added what mutated to:

```
['img/transparent-clock.png','img/hour-hand.png','img/second-hand.png','img/dial-hand.png'].forEach(function(src)
    {
    var img = new Image();
    // img.onload = POCKETWATCH.check_draw_clock;
    img.onerror = function(){ console.log("error"); };
    img.src = src;
    if (img.complete) { POCKETWATCH.check_draw_clock(); }
    console.log(POCKETWATCH.check_draw_clock);
    POCKETWATCH.check_draw_clock();
    });
```

This was not intended as a solution, but for diagnostic purposes. The last real line of code got an error logged that POCKETWATCH.check_draw_clock "is not a function," and then when I logged POCKETWATCH.check_draw_clock, it logged "undefined".

I checked through my code to see if I redefined POCKETWATCH; in the entire code associated with the app, the only time POCKETWATCH is defined is above the quoted code, where it is set to {}. check_draw_clock() is also defined only once.

FWIW.

Comment: `POCKETWATCH.clock_face.onerror = function () { alert("HERE"); };` Does that fire?

Comment: @epascarello, nothing's firing with error handlers attached. Another question I read said you can't count on a load event firing; I'm thinking about simply not waiting for everything to load.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. Which browser are you testing on? Also, do you have you tried in private/incognito mode? Could you provide us a working code on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Don't use `.onload`. Use [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener).

Comment: I haven't tried in incognito mode; a fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/4wnzyg00/ (document.write() call commented out to meet jsfiddle rules).

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the image was cached with complete

```
['img/transparent-clock.png','img/hour-hand.png','img/second-hand.png','img/dial-hand.png'].forEach(function(src){ 
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = POCKETWATCH.check_draw_clock;
    img.onerror = function(){ console.log("error"); };
    img.src = src;
    if (img.complete) { POCKETWATCH.check_draw_clock(); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Went through to console.log check_draw_clock() all the way, and found that the definition of POCKETWATCH was after what I quoted, not before. Now the logging makes sense.